Python Script using Selenium and Chrome webddriver failing on EC2 Linux Instance
I'm trying to automate a python script on AWS EC2 instance using Selenium and Chromedriver, but it's failing for some reason.
I have a python script which takes in an excel file, filters data from it, then uses a column which has tracking IDs for UPS website. The script then webscrapes the current shipment status for all tracking IDs from UPS website and generates a CSV file with the webscraping details in it. The script has been working on my local computer but I'm not being able to run it on EC2 instance for automation.
The path for automation I've taken is that I have setup an S3 bucket with two folders, input and output. An ETL job generates and uploads a new excel file everyday in the S3 bucket. As soon as the excel file hits the input folder, a lambda is triggered which reboots my EC2 instance. Then the python script inside the instance runs, it uses chromedriver and selenium to webscrape the data for all tracking IDs (this is where I'm facing timeout errros) and generates a new dataframe, which is then converted to a csv and exported to the output folder of the s3 bucket.
Here's my code, right now it only takes the first row for testing purposes but not the entire thing, but yeah.
Any help is appreciated!!!
import traceback
import boto3
import pandas as pd
import re
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import io
import logging
from datetime import datetime

# Setup logging
logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.INFO, 
    format='%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s', 
    handlers=[logging.StreamHandler()]
)

# Initialize S3 client
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

# Fetch the latest Excel file from the 'input/' folder of S3 bucket
def fetch_latest_file_from_s3(bucket_name, folder_name='input/'):
    logging.info(f"Fetching the latest file from S3 bucket: {bucket_name}/{folder_name}")
    response = s3_client.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Prefix=folder_name)
    all_files = response.get('Contents', [])
    
    if not all_files:
        logging.error("No files found in the S3 bucket.")
        return None, None

    latest_file = max(all_files, key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
    latest_file_key = latest_file['Key']
    
    logging.info(f"Latest file fetched from S3: {latest_file_key}")
    file_obj = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=latest_file_key)
    file_content = file_obj['Body'].read()
    return file_content, latest_file_key

# Process the data from the file
def process_file_from_s3(file_content):
    logging.info("Processing the file content from S3.")
    df = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(file_content), sheet_name='SPD Base Report', engine='openpyxl')

    logging.info(f"Original DataFrame shape: {df.shape}")
    df['shipment_handed_over_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['shipment_handed_over_timestamp'])

    # Filter rows for testing
    df_filtered = df[df['last_shipment_status'] == "IN_TRANSIT"].head(1)
    df_filtered = df_filtered.sort_values(by='shipment_handed_over_timestamp', ascending=False)

    logging.info(f"Filtered DataFrame shape: {df_filtered.shape}")
    return df_filtered[['pro_id', 'shipment_handed_over_timestamp', 'shipment_id']].dropna().values.tolist()

# Fetch shipment statuses concurrently using Selenium
def fetch_statuses_concurrently(tracking_ids_batch, batch_size=5, max_workers=2):
    logging.info(f"Fetching statuses concurrently for {len(tracking_ids_batch)} tracking IDs.")
    batches = [tracking_ids_batch[i:i + batch_size] for i in range(0, len(tracking_ids_batch), batch_size)]

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=max_workers) as executor:
        results = list(executor.map(get_status_for_batch, batches))

    flattened_results = [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]
    return flattened_results

# Get shipment status for a batch of tracking IDs using Selenium
def get_status_for_batch(tracking_ids_batch):
    logging.info(f"Processing a batch of {len(tracking_ids_batch)} tracking IDs.")
    
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=1920,1080")

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
    results = []

    try:
        for tracking_id, handed_over_timestamp, shipment_id in tracking_ids_batch:
            current_date = pd.Timestamp.now()
            days_diff = (current_date - handed_over_timestamp).days

            if days_diff >= 120:
                logging.warning(f"Skipping {tracking_id}: Shipment information older than 120 days.")
                results.append((tracking_id, shipment_id, handed_over_timestamp, "Older than 120 days", None, None, None))
            else:
                try:
                    ups_url = f"https://www.ups.com/track?tracknum={tracking_id}"
                    driver.get(ups_url)
                    logging.info(f"Page loaded, waiting for status element.")

                    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
                    latest_status_row = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'ups-progress_current_row')))
                    logging.info("Status element found, fetching status text.")

                    status_element = latest_status_row.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'test')
                    latest_status = status_element.text.strip()

                    match = re.search(r'(.+)\n(\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}),\s*(\d{1,2}:\d{2}\s*[APM\.]{2,4})', latest_status)
                    if match:
                        location, date, time = match.groups()
                    else:
                        location, date, time = None, None, None

                    main_status = latest_status.split('\n')[0] if '\n' in latest_status else latest_status
                    results.append((tracking_id, shipment_id, handed_over_timestamp, main_status, location, date, time))
                    logging.info(f"Fetched status for {tracking_id}: {main_status}")
                except TimeoutException as e:
                    logging.error(f"Timeout while fetching status for {tracking_id}: {e}")
                    logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
                    results.append((tracking_id, shipment_id, handed_over_timestamp, "Timeout", None, None, None))
                except Exception as e:
                    logging.error(f"Error while fetching status for {tracking_id}: {e}")
                    logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
                    results.append((tracking_id, shipment_id, handed_over_timestamp, f"Error: {e}", None, None, None))

    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error while processing batch: {e}")
        logging.error(traceback.format_exc())
        results.append((tracking_id, shipment_id, handed_over_timestamp, f"Error: {e}", None, None, None))
    finally:
        driver.quit()

    return results

# Save results to a DataFrame
def save_results_to_df(results):
    logging.info("Saving results to DataFrame.")
    df = pd.DataFrame(results, columns=['Tracking ID', 'Shipment ID', 'Shipment Handed Over to UPS Timestamp', 'Status', 'Location', 'Date', 'Time'])

    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%m/%d/%Y').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    df['Time'] = df['Time'].str.replace(r'\.', '', regex=True)
    df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time'], format='%I:%M %p').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    df['Timestamp'] = df['Date'] + ' ' + df['Time']
    df.drop(columns=['Date', 'Time'], inplace=True)

    logging.info(f"Resulting DataFrame shape: {df.shape}")
    return df

# Upload the output CSV to S3
def upload_output_to_s3(df, bucket_name, original_key):
    logging.info("Uploading the results to S3.")
    csv_buffer = io.StringIO()
    df.to_csv(csv_buffer, index=False)

    output_key = original_key.replace('input/', 'output/').replace('.xlsx', '.csv')
    s3_client.put_object(Bucket=bucket_name, Key=output_key, Body=csv_buffer.getvalue())
    logging.info(f"File uploaded to S3 at {output_key}")

# Main function to execute
def main():
    logging.info("Starting SPD Carrier Tracking script.")
    bucket_name = 'awd-spd-carrier-tracking'

    # Fetch the latest Excel file from S3
    file_content, file_key = fetch_latest_file_from_s3(bucket_name)
    if not file_content:
        logging.error("No valid file content to process. Exiting.")
        return

    # Process the Excel file and get tracking IDs
    tracking_ids_batch = process_file_from_s3(file_content)

    # Fetch shipment statuses for the tracking IDs
    statuses = fetch_statuses_concurrently(tracking_ids_batch)

    # Save the results to a DataFrame
    output_df = save_results_to_df(statuses)

    # Upload the results to S3
    upload_output_to_s3(output_df, bucket_name, file_key)

    logging.info("SPD Carrier Tracking script completed successfully.")

# Run the script
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()


This is what I get in the console after I run the code :
2024-10-25 22:38:41,441 - INFO - Found credentials from IAM Role: ec2instanceaccessrole-...
2024-10-25 22:38:41,569 - INFO - Starting SPD Carrier Tracking script.
2024-10-25 22:38:41,569 - INFO - Fetching the latest file from S3 bucket: awd-spd-carrier-tracking/input/
2024-10-25 22:38:41,644 - INFO - Latest file fetched from S3: input/MCD_Base_Report.xlsx
2024-10-25 22:38:41,787 - INFO - Processing the file content from S3.
2024-10-25 22:38:45,439 - INFO - Original DataFrame shape: (12839, 25)
2024-10-25 22:38:45,463 - INFO - Filtered DataFrame shape: (1, 25)
2024-10-25 22:38:45,465 - INFO - Fetching statuses concurrently for 1 tracking IDs.
2024-10-25 22:38:45,466 - INFO - Processing a batch of 1 tracking IDs.
2024-10-25 22:38:45,466 - INFO - ====== WebDriver manager ======
2024-10-25 22:38:45,767 - INFO - Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome
2024-10-25 22:38:45,850 - INFO - Get LATEST chromedriver version for google-chrome
2024-10-25 22:38:45,910 - INFO - Driver [/root/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/130.0.6723.69/chromedriver-linux64/chromedriver] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/spd_carrier_tracking.py", line 185, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/ec2-user/spd_carrier_tracking.py", line 173, in main
    statuses = fetch_statuses_concurrently(tracking_ids_batch)
  File "/home/ec2-user/spd_carrier_tracking.py", line 68, in fetch_statuses_concurrently
    results = list(executor.map(get_status_for_batch, batches))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 609, in result_iterator
    yield fs.pop().result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 446, in result
    return self.__get_result()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 391, in __get_result
    raise self._exception
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.9/concurrent/futures/thread.py", line 58, in run
    result = self.fn(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/spd_carrier_tracking.py", line 83, in get_status_for_batch
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py", line 66, in __init__
    super().__init__(command_executor=executor, options=options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 299, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 354, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 229, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: Chrome failed to start: exited normally.
  (session not created: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /opt/google/chrome/chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace:
#0 0x56203364410a <unknown>
#1 0x56203315f460 <unknown>
#2 0x56203319522a <unknown>
#3 0x562033190ca5 <unknown>
#4 0x5620331dc156 <unknown>
#5 0x5620331db7a6 <unknown>
#6 0x5620331cfdb3 <unknown>
#7 0x56203319ec10 <unknown>
#8 0x56203319fbee <unknown>
#9 0x56203361039b <unknown>
#10 0x562033614338 <unknown>
#11 0x5620335fdebc <unknown>
#12 0x562033614eb7 <unknown>
#13 0x5620335e310f <unknown>
#14 0x562033632828 <unknown>
#15 0x5620336329f0 <unknown>
#16 0x562033642f86 <unknown>
#17 0x7f227d49f7f2 start_thread

I made sure all the libraries are downloaded, the chromedriver and chrome versions are the same. Been trying to figure this out for the last 2 days!
